# Recommended resources for learning Service Workers and IndexedDB in Angular

Tags: angular, indexeddb, angular-service-worker

I'm an Angular developer with some experience, and I'm looking to learn more about Service Workers and IndexedDB to enhance my web app's offline capabilities. I've done some initial research, but I'm seeking recommendations for the best tutorials, books, or online courses to dive deeper into these topics.

I'd prefer resources that are up-to-date and suitable for Angular (latest version if possible). Please share your suggestions, and if you have personal experience with a particular resource, I'd appreciate hearing about that as well. Thanks in advance!

I'm a beginner and I'm just getting started with Service Workers and IndexedDB in Angular. I haven't tried anything yet. I'm looking for advice and resources to kickstart my learning journey in these areas.